# Display static message for empty values

Tags: php

i tried below code to fetch results of column **dpaid_status** from mysql database & its working fine:

**Database**

[image]

**site**

[image]

```
$i = 0; 
foreach($order as $orderData) 
{ 
$k = 0; 
$orderitems = $orderData['dproduct_id']; 
$orderitemsarray = explode(",", $orderitems); 

while ($k < count($orderitemsarray)) 

    { 

if ($orderitemsarray[$k] != '0') 
    { 

$stmtorders = $user_home->runQuery("SELECT * FROM order_details"); 
$stmtorders->execute(array(":dorder_id" => $orderData['entity_id'])); 

$roworders = $stmtorders->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 

$dorderStatus = $roworders['dpaid_status']; 

$productdetail = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($orderitemsarray[$k]); 
$designer_id = $productdetail->getDesignerID() ; 

if($accountType == "admin")
{ 
$designerName = getDesignerName($productdetail->getDesignerID()) . " -(" . $productdetail->getDesignerID() . ")"; 

$stmt1 = $user_home->runQuery("SELECT * FROM order_details WHERE dproduct_id=:pid and designerorder_id=:doid");
    $stmt1->execute(array(
        ":doid" => $orderData->getIncrementId(),
        ":pid" => $orderitemsarray[$k],
    ));

    $paid_status='';
    while($datas = $stmt1->fetch())

{
    $paid_status=$datas['dpaid_status'];
}

$responce[] = array( 
$paid_status
); 

return json_encode($responce);
```

But for some columns there is no value for dpaid_status, so i wanted to display **none** for those in page. so instead of `$paid_status=$datas['dpaid_status'];` i tried below code ,

```
    if ($roworders['dorder_id'] == '')
    {
     $paid_status='unpaid';
    }
    else
    {
     $paid_status=$datas['dpaid_status'];
    }
```

ex : in above image there is no row for "15585" in database , so it should display `unpaid` for that.... but now its displaying blank....

Comment: if anyone want to check full code : http://pastebin.com/GFr559qF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check your `$paid_status` variable right before returning/using it. This way you will catch all cases when the value is empty (either empty value in the table or missing row in the database table).
I have added the new lines to your code, below:

```
$stmt1 = $user_home->runQuery("SELECT * FROM order_details WHERE dproduct_id=:pid and designerorder_id=:doid");
    $stmt1->execute(array(
        ":doid" => $orderData->getIncrementId(),
        ":pid" => $orderitemsarray[$k],
    ));

    $paid_status='';
    while($datas = $stmt1->fetch())

{
    $paid_status=$datas['dpaid_status'];
}

//added new lines of code here - START
if ( $paid_status == ''){
     $paid_status='unpaid';
}
//added new lines of code here - END

$responce[] = array( 
$paid_status
);
```

Comment: I'm glad I could help

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($roworders['dpaid_status'] != '')
{
    $paid_status=$datas['dpaid_status'];
}
else
{
   $paid_status='unpaid';
}
```

Comment: sorry, may be i didt explained in question correctly, i didt wanted this one, all i wanted is instead of `blank`, i want to display `unpaid`.....

Comment: your code is replacing `U` by `unpaid` but i want to  display `unpaid` only on blank spaces.....

Comment: mention the output am not clear what you are asking?

Comment: well, can you please see image under text `site` in question, if you see there, you can see value `U` for 2nd and 3rd row, but for 1st row its displaying blank, in that place i want to display `unpaid`

Comment: i tried , now same result as in question. one thing is in database `15585` row is not available.

Comment: as 15585 row is not available in database, still can we achieve result with help of this condition `if ($roworders['dpaid_status'] != '')` ?

Comment: you need to fetch all the records right but before displaying on the view  you need to check the condition of this paid_status am i right??

Comment: okay, now is there any chance that i can display `unpaid` for those , means if there is no rows, because i am fetching those rows from some other database.....

Comment: let me clear, we are fetching all the other columns from 1st database & paid status from 2nd database and displaying in page. in 1st db there are 10 records & in 2nd there are 5 record, for those 5 records  i can get value from 2nd db i.e : `U` for other 5 records which are not in 2nd database, i need to display `unpaid`, please let me know if you have any doubts.....

Comment: see site is result getting from the database right when you are displaying the results in view page check the condition whether the dpaid_status is empty or not if it is not empty dispalay the result else display the static result as unpaid

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130777/discussion-between-abcd-and-soniya-reddy).

Comment: thanks a lot for your support i found solution......, i am extremely sorry that i did't able to solve issue with your help as i have lack of knowledge in both php & mysql

Answer (score 0):

You can solve the problem also at SQL level, just using a query like:

`SELECT [field_list], IFNULL(dpaid_status, 'unpaid') as paid_status  FROM order_details`

which return the dpaid_status value if the field is not null, else return 'unpaid'

Comment: thanks, i am new to php, i tried like this : `$sql = SELECT * IF NULL(dpaid_status, 'unpaid') as paid_status  FROM order_details;
    $paid_status = $conn->query($sql);` i am getting error : `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'IF' (T_IF) `

Comment: sorry for that, when i tried this : `$sql = SELECT * IFNULL(dpaid_status, 'unpaid') as paid_status  FROM order_details;`  i got `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'as' (T_AS)`

Comment: thanks a lot for your support i found solution......, i am extremely sorry that i did't able to solve issue with your help as i have lack of knowledge in both php & mysql

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use PHP `empty()`.

> Determine whether a variable is considered to be empty. A variable is
>   considered empty if it does not exist or if its value equals FALSE.
>   empty() does not generate a warning if the variable does not exist.

The following things are considered to be empty:

> - "" (an empty string)
> - 0 (0 as an integer)
> - 0.0 (0 as a float)
> - "0" (0 as a string)
> - NULL
> - FALSE
> - array() (an empty array)
> - $var; (a variable declared, but without a value)

so your `if` statement can be written

```
if (empty($roworders['dpaid_status']))
{
 $paid_status='unpaid';
}
else
{
 $paid_status=$datas['dpaid_status'];
}
```

Comment: can you please help me : [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41238427/converting-date-in-m-d-y-format-leads-to-display-date-in-other-rows)