# Converting Date in M d, Y format leads to display date in other rows

Tags: php, date-formatting

We are fetching values of column **"due_date"** & displaying in site.

[image]

Its working fine with help of below code.

[image]

```
$i = 0; 
foreach($order as $orderData) 
{ 
    $k = 0; 

    while ($k < count($orderitemsarray)) { 

        if ($orderitemsarray[$k] != '0') { 

            if($accountType == "admin") { 
                $due_date='';

                while($datas = $stmt1->fetch()) {
                    $due_date=$datas['due_date'];
                    $oDate1 = new DateTime($datas['due_date']); 
                    $sDate1 = $oDate1->format("M d, Y");
                }

                $responce[] = array( $due_date ); 

            }

            return json_encode($responce);
```

**script**

```
var colsOption = [
   {id: 'due_date' , header: " Due Date" , width :"140"},
];
```

I want to display date in this format : [image]

so i tried below code

```
$responce[] = array( 
   $sDate1
    );
```

Now its displaying Date for other rows also, but for those other rows there is **no values [ Due date ]  in Database.**

[image]

Comment: Check you PHP script now that it has been properly indented

Comment: Thanks a lot @RiggsFolly , its look fantastic now, in future i will not do these mistakes......

Comment: does the query return only the date field?

Comment: @PeterDarmis yes it will return only `Date` , no time.....

Comment: so basically you are using json encode on an array of dates or is there anything other stored in `response`?

Comment: @PeterDarmis we have like this : `$responce[] = array( 
$orderData->getIncrementId() , 
$orderData->getIncrementId() , 
$orderitemsarray[$k], 
$productdetail->getName() , 
$designerName, 
$orderData['status'], // magento [ pending / processing/complete] 
$orderData['grand_total'], // magento 
$orderData['customer_email'], // magento 
$commission, 
$paid_status, 
$delivery_status,
$due_date,
$sDate // magento 
); `

Comment: @PeterDarmis means other than `Date` we are storing some other values also like `product, status`.... etc.....

Comment: ok sorry then i must edit my answer

Comment: @PeterDarmis i tried your answer , seems i am doing something wrong, can you please join  : http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131037/discussion-between-abcd-and-ronald-swets or you can edit answer and let me know

Comment: @PeterDarmis can you please join : http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131037/discussion-between-abcd-and-ronald-swets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you your are adding values in $response[] using loop. What happens is that value of $sDate1 is not initialized to null. So when it is set for first time it does not change until next due_date value comes so it keeps on repeating last $sDate1 value to solve this , Go to line 152 in this file http://pastebin.com/PnPnX9Wiand bellow it initialize $sDate1. Make changes in this code.

```
$paid_status='';
$delivery_status='';
$due_date='';
```

Add $sDate1='';. It will look like this.

```
    $paid_status='';
    $delivery_status='';
    $due_date='';
    $sDate1='';
```

Now change this code.

```
    $due_date=$datas['due_date'];
    $oDate1 = new DateTime($datas['due_date']); 
    $sDate1 = $oDate1->format("M d, Y");
```

with this code.

```
$oDate1 = new DateTime($datas['due_date']);
$due_date = $oDate1->format("M d, Y");
$sDate1 = $oDate1->format("M d, Y");
```

Comment: In your code there is if and else in if part code is for admin and in else part it is for normal user. so make sure if you have made your changes in admin part of code. You are cheeking it in admin panel. Not in user panel.

Comment: yes, i tried your code in both in admin & user panel, still not working for me.....

Answer (score 0):

Updated the code after reading the pastebin (see comments below).

```
            $sDate1 = '';
            while($datas = $stmt1->fetch()) {
                if ($datas['due_date'] != null) {
                    $oDate1 = new DateTime($datas['due_date']); 
                    $sDate1 = $oDate1->format("M d, Y");
                }
            }

            $responce[] = array( $sDate1 );
```

Comment: sorry, i really didt got, can you please explain little bit what code i need to change ?

Comment: I cannot exactly tell you, since i don't know what the output 'should' be.

Comment: i need the output as like 2nd image in question but instead of `2016-12-15`, it should be `Dec 5 2016`

Comment: please check updated question, i was trying : `$responce[] = array( 
   $sDate1
    );`

Comment: Is the response array supposed to only have one value? Then the loop would not be necessary. Else this is supposed to go inside the fetch-loop.

Comment: actually i have more values inside `responce array` , to reduce unneccessary code, i removed the other code, you can check complete code here : http://pastebin.com/ciztBvEZ

Comment: After reading the pastebin: You can use $sDate in your response, although make sure you initialize it to empty as well. See updated answer.

Comment: sorry, still its giving me same result, please check updated code : http://pastebin.com/PnPnX9Wi

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply check for empty date

```
 while($datas = $stmt1->fetch()) {
      $due_date=$datas['due_date'];
      if(isset($due_date)){  // Apply the check for empty if empty dont pass it to Datetime function.
      $oDate1 = new DateTime($datas['due_date']); 
      $sDate1 = $oDate1->format("M d, Y");  
      $responce[] =  $sDate1;
      }
 }`
```

Comment: sorry, still it displaying same result, please check updated question, i was trying : `$responce[] = array( 
   $sDate1
    );`

Comment: are you telling me to update `$responce[] =  $sDate1;` code inside `if condition` , i tried that, but it did't worked for me, also i tried  if condition with including `$responce[] =  $sDate1;` outside `if condition` that one also didt worked for me....

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this part...

```
        while($datas = $stmt1->fetch()) {
                $due_date=$datas['due_date'];
                $oDate1 = new DateTime($datas['due_date']); 
                $sDate1 = $oDate1->format("M d, Y");
            }

            $responce[] = array( $due_date ); 

        }

        return json_encode($responce);
```

Try something like this...

```
        $response = array();
        ...

$i = 0; 
foreach($order as $orderData) 
{ 
$k = 0; 

while ($k < count($orderitemsarray)) { 

    if ($orderitemsarray[$k] != '0') { 

        if($accountType == "admin") { 

        while($datas = $stmt1->fetch()) {
             if(!empty($datas['due_date'])){ 
                // place the Datetime part here... in case $datas['due_date'] is empty*
                $oDate1 = new DateTime($datas['due_date']); 
                $due_date = $oDate1->format("M d, Y");
              } else {
                $due_date = "";
              } 
            }
        ...
        ...
        return json_encode($responce);
        ...
```

(*) check the output of Datetime [here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/451bd0cc69f5c82f21e1ab098c0a2368633b6aff) if `$datas['due_date']` is "" or `null`

Answer (score 0):

You need to check variable is empty or not and then format the date this the updated code

```
$i = 0; 
foreach($order as $orderData) 
{ 
$k = 0; 

while ($k < count($orderitemsarray)) { 

    if ($orderitemsarray[$k] != '0') { 

        if($accountType == "admin") { 
            $due_date='';

            while($datas = $stmt1->fetch()) {
                $due_date=$datas['due_date'];
                $oDate1 = new DateTime($datas['due_date']); 
                if (!empty($oDate1))
                    $sDate1 = $oDate1->format("M d, Y");
            }

            $responce[] = array( $due_date ); 

        }

        return json_encode($responce);
```

Comment: have you got the result